# Random number generation in my implementation

Tags: c, random

Is this implementation of random number generation wrong?

```
int random_number(int l, int u)
{
    int num;
    num = rand()%u;
    if (num<l && num>u)
    {
        while(num<l && num>u)
        {
            num = rand()%u;
        }   
    }
    return num;
}
```

This is not giving me the correct answer.
If I try random_number(4,8); it generates numbers like 0,1,2 etc.

Comment: How can `num` be less than `l`  AND more than `u`? Also, the `if` is unnecessary - `while` is doing that job. But it's a poor algorithm that hunts for a number: it might *never* find one that satisfies!

Comment: @WeatherVane easy, if `l > (u+1)`.

Comment: @EOF another good reason not to use single-letter variable names - especially `l` which can be confused with `1`. Stupid WV thinks they are short for `lower` and `upper`, not `larger` and `under`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Oh, I have no doubt they stand for `lower` and `upper`. I was just being my usual charmingly pedantic self.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `u` means upper and `l` means lower, then it is wrong. Try this:

```
int random_number(int l, int u) {
    int num = rand() % (u - l);
    return num + l;
}
```

Comment: That is, `l <= number < u`.

Comment: `rand() % (u-l+1)`

Comment: This worked thanks, I now know where my implementation went wrong

Comment: Hi gratttt and welcome to StackOverflow. If you found a solution, you should mark the answer as accepted. -- http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Consider the lines.

```
int random_number(int l, int u)
  num = rand()%u  // result 0, 1, 3, .... 7
  if (num<l && num>u)

random_number(4,8);
```

Code needs to follow the `if()` when `num <4` **and** `num > 8`.  An `int` cannot both be less than 4 and greater than 8 at the same time.

The usual idiom is

```
int random_number(int lower, int upper) {
  int num;
  num = rand()%(upper - lower + 1) + lower;
  return num;
}
```

Extra code is needed to cope/detect `upper < lower`, `upper - lower >= RAND_MAX`